# How to send a single email to all people in a column

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found macros to send an email to each person in a column.

[image: It should send emails to all persons in column B.]

Column B shows the names which have "Yes" in column C. I have added this condition in Power Query.

```vb
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_Attachment_1()
    'Working in 2000-2016
    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim intHowManyRows As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    intHowManyRows = Application.Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For r = 1 To intHowManyRows
        'Save, Mail, Close and Delete the file
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Value
            ' Cells(r, 2).Value
            .Subject = Cells(r, 3).Value
            '.Attachments.Add FullName  -> If you want to add attachments
            .Body = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "How are you " & Cells(r, 2)
            .Display  'Or use Send
        End With
    Next r

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Or:

```vb
Sub Test2()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
      LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I want to generate a single Outlook mail with all persons in column B in the "To" and also attach a file.

Comment: If you want one single email, then you need to get rid of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted Ron's code. See my comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

**EDIT:** As per niton's suggestion, remove the on error resume next and see what line causes the error.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendEmail()
    ' For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    ' Adapted by Ricardo Diaz ricardodiaz.co
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Dim evalRow As ListRow

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim toArray() As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set sourceTable = Range("Table1").ListObject ' -> Set the table's name

    On Error GoTo cleanup


    ' Loop through each table's rows
    For Each evalRow In sourceTable.ListRows

        If evalRow.Range.Cells(, 2).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(evalRow.Range.Cells(, 3).Value) = "yes" Then
            ReDim Preserve toArray(counter)
            toArray(counter) = evalRow.Range.Cells(, 2).Value
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

    Next evalRow

    ' Setup the email
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    With OutMail
        ' Add gathered recipients
        For counter = 0 To UBound(toArray)
            .Recipients.Add (toArray(counter))
        Next counter

        .Subject = "Reminder"

        .Body = "Dear All" _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                "your account up to date"

        'You can add files also like this
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt") ' -> Adjust this path

        .Send ' -> Or use Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Ricardo This works but when I change  it to .display instead of .send , it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hi Roy, check if the path to the attachment is correct

Comment: Seeing errors allows code to be debugged. Remove `On Error GoTo cleanup` and `On Error Resume Next` http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: Hi Ricardo    So when I comment the attachment and use ".display" it does work. But i want to run this macro after a macro is run. After the first macro run , I have a new sheet added to the file which has the "Missing Units". From this sheet I want to lookup for unique values from a column and based on the unique values from that column my table (used in your Macro) will show up only the unique names from the column in it and then i use your macro to send out emails to all with attachment. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Roy if the answer works, please remember to mark it so others may find it. As per your other requirement, I suggest that you post a new question, and if you want, post the link here and I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Hi Ricardo   Here's the link to the new question.             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903072/macro-to-send-emails-all-people-by-looking-for-unique-values-in-a-columngenerat

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz    Please help with this question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379882/macro-to-copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-a-template-based-on-condition